# Cannot uninstall or modify old Visual Studio versions (2012 and 2015)

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, visual-studio

I am running Windows 10. I have Visual Studio Professional 2012, 2015 and 2019 installed. I want to get rid of 2012 and 2015. So I go to Start Menu -> Apps & features.

1. If I unfold VS 2019, I have a "Modify" and an "Uninstall" button. If I click "Modify", I see no option to modify or uninstall the older versions.
2. If I unfold VS 2012 or VS 2015, "Uninstall" is grayed out. If I click "Modify" and allow vs_professional.exe to run, I get a popup saying: "Microsoft .NET Framework required for Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 setup". If I click "Decline" it just aborts. If I click "Accept & Install", it runs for a little while, then closes, apparently without doing anything. If I then click "Modify" again I get the same thing. Rebooting after this step did not help.
   [image: .NET prompt]
3. If I try to uninstall from the old-fashioned Control Panel -> Programs and Features, I get the same prompt.
4. If I run an installer EXE for VS 2015, I get the same prompt.
5. I cannot "repair" the old installations of VS either, since I can't get past the prompt above. I can still RUN the old VS, though.

So for some reason I cannot run the installers for old versions of Visual Studio. How can I debug this?

I cannot find anything that looks interesting in my Event Viewer.

According to my Windows features I have all visible .NET versions installed.
[image: Windows features]

Comment: Was this always a Windows 10 or is it upgraded from some previous Windows? Also, which release?

Comment: This was always Windows 10. My "version" is 2004 and my "OS build" is 19041.450.